# Extracting coordinates from indices

Tags: matlab, coordinates, cell, indices

I am trying to create a distribution and then based on a certain condition I remove some particles and keep the others and arrange them in a row vector form. Once, the filtering is done , I want to store the coordinates of the left over points via the indices.

My idea was to use the indices to extract the coordinates posx,posy,posz which satisfy the condition. 
I am unable to do this. Following is the code. Any and all inputs will be helpful guys. Any simpler method would be most helpful. 
I am new to Matlab so please forgive my naive question. 
Thanks
.
.
.

```
clear all;
%=============Minimum Allowable Distance/Blockade Radius=====================

blockade =  15*10^-6;% blockade radius in um

%=============Sigma of the RED LASER beam from the SLM=====================

sigmax = 10;% 1-sigma x of the SLM beam in um
sigmay = 10;% 1-sigma y of the SLM beam in um

%=============Sigma of the BLUE LASER beam from the SLM====================

sigmaz = 10;% sigma z of the blue beam in um

%==================Number of Scan Steps====================================

npics =500; %number of iterations

%=============Number of initial particles in the excitation volume in the MOT Stage===================

numberofparticles = 100; % Number of points per iteration
%=============Creating a cell system for importing GPT Data into===========

l = cell(numberofparticles,1);
distances = cell(npics,1);

posx = cell(npics,1);
posy = cell(npics,1);
posz = cell(npics,1);

for n=1:1:npics
    fprintf(' %d ', n);
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %                                         SECTION 1:  Creating Distributions
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    %============Declaration of orgin for simulation===========================

    mux = 0;
    muy = 0;
    muz = 0;

    %=============Creating a x,y,z coordinate system for the ion===============

    x = normrnd(mux,sigmax*10^-6,[1 numberofparticles]);
    y = normrnd(muy,sigmay*10^-6,[1 numberofparticles]);
    z = normrnd(muz,sigmaz*10^-6,[1 numberofparticles]);


    %%%%%%%%%%%%%METHOD 2%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    for i =  1:1:length(l)

        for j = 1:1:length(l)

            distances{i}{j} = sqrt((x(i) - x(j)).^2 + (y(i) - y(j)).^2 + (z(i) - z(j)).^2);

            if distances{i}{j} < blockade
                distances{i}{j} = 0;
            end

            if distances{i}{j} >= blockade
                posx{j} = x(j);
                posy{j} = y(j);
                posz{j} = z(j);
            end

        end



    end

end
```

Comment: What are npics, length(l) and blockage? There are also too many unknown variable, so we cannot run the code. You'll need to give us some more info.

Comment: blockade =  15*10^-6;% Minimum Allowable Distance b/w 2 points created by normrnd

sigmax = 10;% 1-sigma x of the SLM beam in um
sigmay = 10;% sigma y of the SLM beam in um
sigmaz = 10;% sigma z of the blue beam in um
npics =2; %number of iterations
numberofparticles = 100;
l = cell(numberofparticles,1);
distances = cell(npics,1);

posx = cell(npics,1);
posy = cell(npics,1);
posz = cell(npics,1);

Comment: Edit your question with the whole code. The edit button is at the left below your post.

Comment: Cool thanks :) .will do now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code deletes the points that lie too close to each other according to your "distance" criterion. There was no need to use "distance" as a cell array because you were not doing anything with it. In fact, if you don't re-use something, don't store all their values. I put the coordinates in `allpoints` so that they are always kept together.

```
clear all;
%=============Minimum Allowable Distance/Blockade Radius=====================

blockade =  15*10^-6;% blockade radius in um

%=============Sigma of the RED LASER beam from the SLM=====================

sigmax = 10;% 1-sigma x of the SLM beam in um
sigmay = 10;% 1-sigma y of the SLM beam in um

%=============Sigma of the BLUE LASER beam from the SLM====================

sigmaz = 10;% sigma z of the blue beam in um

%==================Number of Scan Steps====================================

npics =2; %number of iterations

%=============Number of initial particles in the excitation volume in the MOT Stage===================

numberofparticles = 100; % Number of points per iteration


allpoints = cell(npics,1);


for n=1:npics
    fprintf(' %d ', n);
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %                                         SECTION 1:  Creating Distributions
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    %============Declaration of orgin for simulation===========================

    mux = 0;
    muy = 0;
    muz = 0;

    %=============Creating a x,y,z coordinate system for the ion===============

    x = normrnd(mux,sigmax*10^-6,[1 numberofparticles]);
    y = normrnd(muy,sigmay*10^-6,[1 numberofparticles]);
    z = normrnd(muz,sigmaz*10^-6,[1 numberofparticles]);

    figure(n)
    plot(x,y,'r*')
    hold on

    allpoints = cell(npics,1);

    for i = 1:length(x)

        allpoints{i} = [x(i) y(i) z(i)]; % Store all coordinates in 1 cell array

    end


    %%%%%%%%%%%%%METHOD 2%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

   % Because allpoints will change size (some points are removed if "distance" is smaller than blockade, we cannot use a for-loop i=1:length(allpoints) because then the max value of i is already fixed while allpoints will only get smaller. Therefore, i will get larger than the eventual length of allpoints

   i = 1;
   j = 1;  

   while true % As long as i is not larger than the length of allpoints, not all points have been evaluated with each other

       j = i+1;

        while true   

            coordi = allpoints{i};        
            coordj = allpoints{j};

            distances = sqrt((coordi(1) - coordj(1)).^2 + (coordi(2) - coordj(2)).^2 + (coordi(3) - coordj(3)).^2);

            if distances < blockade
                allpoints(j) = []; % Using the round brackets, the cell is deleted 
                    % When a point is removed from the list, j does not need to be increased because the next point that needs to be evaluated comes at the place of the old point, so at position j and not j+1
            else
                j = j + 1; % Increase j to evaluate the next point. 
            end

            if j>length(allpoints)
                break;
            end

        end

        i = i + 1;

        if i>= length(allpoints)
            break;
        end

   end

   allpoints = cell2mat(allpoints);

    plot(allpoints(:,1),allpoints(:,2),'bo')

end
```

Comment: Thanks for the great advise with the selection criterion. Thanks again for the hep with the code. :)

Comment: Ya it is :). Thanks a lot again.

Comment: Good to hear. Can you accept the answer so that the question is closed?

Answer (score 0):

I'll give it an attempt, but you have some variables that aren't defined in the code you posted.  I put comments in my code where those places are.

```
%Initialize >>npics variable here
%Initialize some vectors and matrices that were not in your code
distances = zeros(1,maxDistances) %maxDistances is a number that represents how many distances you will have to index into this vector
posx = zeros(1,maxPosx); posy = zeros(1,maxPosy); posz = zeros(1,maxPosz)
for n = 1 : 1 : npics
    fprintf('%d',n);

    %SECTION 1:  Creating Distributions


    %Declaration of orgin for simulation
    mux = 0; muy = 0; muz = 0; 

    %mean for the normrnd. We set the mean to zero to start from zero. 
    %Creating a x,y,z coordinate system for the ion
    x = normrnd(mux,sigmax*10^-6,[1 numberofparticles]);
    y = normrnd(muy,sigmay*10^-6,[1 numberofparticles]);
    z = normrnd(muz,sigmaz*10^-6,[1 numberofparticles]);

    for ii =  1 : 1 : length(l)

        for jj = 1 : 1 : length(l)

                distances{ii}{jj} = sqrt((x(ii) - x(jj)).^2 + (y(ii) - y(jj)).^2 + (z(ii) - z(jj)).^2);

                if distances{ii}{jj} < blockade %blockade is undefined; you must put some `Bool` or `Int` value here, or set its value earlier in your code
                    distances{ii}{jj} = 0;
                elseif distances{ii}{jj} >= blockade
                    posx(n) = x(jj);
                    posy(n) = y(jj);
                    posz(n) = z(jj);
                end
        end
    end
end
```

All I did to your code was, based on the conditions, I placed the items that met those conditions into an empty row vector.  Is this what you wanted because your specifications were a little unclear and your code was missing a few initialized variables?

Also, why do you have two `for` loops that have the same endpoint?  Do you want to get the index values for a matrix?

Also, you're missing the initialization of the `sigma` parameter for the `normrnd` function.  You can read about it [here on the MathWorks documentation.](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/normrnd.html)

Comment: Hi Programming Enthusiast. Thanks a lot for your help. I had earlier thought of using the indices to extract the posx,posy,posz but based on your method I think since I already have them in the row vector. It should be possible. The cell structure in matlab has been baffling me a little to be honest.

Comment: @Tarun No problem!  If you have any more problems with it, just let me know!  The cell structure is confusing, therefore, I'd try to just use `for` loops with row-column indexing like you sort of do here.  If this helped, please be sure to approve the answer!

Comment: Hi Programming Enthusiast. Thanks a lot for your help. :)